# Why `driver.find_elements_by_class_name().click()` results in `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'click'`?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium

When I tried to click a button by using Python Selenium,
I got the following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 53, in <module>
    button.click()
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'click'
```

Did I miss choose the element?

```
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
driver.get('https://website.com/signup')
time.sleep(1)

button = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("continue")
button.click()
time.sleep(1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`find_elements_by_class_name` returns all of the found elements in a `list`. You should most likely use [`find_element_by_name`](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html#locating-by-name):

```
button = driver.find_element_by_name("continue")
button.click()
```